# Перенесение узлов в бинарном дереве

Tags: python, алгоритм, дерево

Есть бинарное дерево, построенное из отсортированного списка. По условию задачи в дереве происходит смена узлов местами, и вместе с узлами, меняются местами и их потомки.

На вход дается список:

```
tree = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Затем из списка строится дерево:

[image: tree]

Затем происходит замена узлов 5 и 2 местами, причем замена происходит вместе с потомками узлов, и дерево должно выглядить так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем дерево переносится в список, и список должен выглядеть так:

```
tree = [1, 5, 3, 10, 2, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9]
```

Каким образом реализовать функцию, которая будет переносить узлы дерева вместе с потомками?

Comment: `Каким образом реализовать функцию, которая будет создавать новый список` - обход дерева в ширину и будет новый список

Comment: Михаил, спасибо! Не могли бы Вы продемонстрировать как это может быть реализовано на данном примере?

Comment: https://pythonist.ru/poisk-v-shirinu-na-python/

Comment: @MBo в смысле? Узлы не поменяются местами от того что мы обойдем дерево в ширину. Он спрашивал как получить список `[1, 5, 3, 10, 2, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9]` из второго дерева и я написал, что он может быть получен обходом в ширину.

Comment: @MBo в данном вопросе замена узлов - это  свершившийся факт описанный в условии, а не часть задачи, которая ставится автором.

Comment: @Михаил Ребров Так дело только в выводе, а сам обмен в задачу не входит? Вот как, значит, я недопонял вопрос.

Comment: Обмен в задачу входит. Вероятно я неправильно пояснил, что требуется сделать. На вход дается список, из него строится дерево, в дереве узлы меняются местами (вместе с потомками), новое дерево нужно перенести в список.

Comment: вы приведите пример того что подается на вход программы

Comment: 1) На вход подается список.
2) Из списка формируется дерево.
3) В дереве происходит замена узлов равных 5 и 2, с переносом их потомков.
Именно на этом этапе я столкнулся с той проблемой, что не знаю как это реализовать.
4)Из измененного дерева сформировать список.

Answer (score 0):

решение по [ссылке](https://pythonist.ru/poisk-v-shirinu-na-python/) из комментариев конечно интересное, но сразу три рекурсивные функции выглядят сложно, есть способ попроще:

```
tree = []
q = [root]  # root - корневой узел, в нашем случае - 1
while q:
    for _ in range(len(q)):
        cur = q.pop(0)
        tree.append(cur.value)
        if cur.left: q.append(cur.left)
        if cur.right: q.append(cur.right)

>>> tree # [1, 5, 3, 10, 2, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. Но проблема в том, что я знаю как из исходного списка [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] построить дерево. Затем по условию задачи узлы 2 и 5 меняются местами, причем меняются местами вместе с переносом потомков, как на втором рисунке. Я не знаю как реализовать эту замену. Обход в ширину позволит мне найти меняемый узел и изменить его значение, но я не знаю как перетащить всех его потомков в правильном порядке.

Comment: @Alexey2702 так это совсем другое дело, изначально вопрос стоял иначе

Answer (score 0):

Проверить, не является ли один из узлов потомком другого. Если да, то сначала отсоединить дерево потомка от его родителя, затем второй узел от его родителя. Если такой зависимости нет, то отсоединять в любом порядке.

Теперь присоединить первый узел на место второго и наоборот.

О существенном: описание дерева по уровням не даёт однозначной информации о его структуре, это прокатывает только для полного бинарного дерева (как на первой картинке, все уровни заполнены, кроме, возможно, последнего)